# how to get fullDocument from mongoDb when partlicular document is updated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, changestream

Actually, I am working on a change stream in Node.js (Express.js).
I got stuck in the below situation.

here i have made Database Connetion with mongoDB using mongoose

```
async function main() {
    const uri = process.env.DATABASE;
    const client = mongoose.connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        reconnectInterval: 500, // Reconnect every 500m
    })

    // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
    await client
        .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))
        .catch(er => console.log(er));


    const pipeline = [
        {
            '$match': {
                $or: [{ operationType: 'insert' }, { operationType: 'update' }]

            }
        }
    ];
    await monitorListingsUsingEventEmitter(client, 30000,pipeline);



}

main().catch(console.error);
```

this is function for change stream

```
async function monitorListingsUsingEventEmitter(client, timeInMs = 60000, pipeline = []) {


    const changeStream = await members.watch(pipeline);

    changeStream.on('change', async (next) => {
        switch (next.operationType) {
            case 'insert':
                console.log('an insert happened...', "uni_ID: ", next.fullDocument);
                break;

            case 'update':
                console.log('an update happened...', next.fullDocument);
//
//getting undefined in above line because there is no property name 'fullDocument' in object next
//      
                break;

            case 'delete':
                console.log('a delete happened...');
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    });
```

overall my question is that :

> *I need a full document object that is getting updated without any query*

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the variable `pipeline` to the `monitorListingsUsingEventEmitter`? The way you write it, the `pipeline` will be empty. Also, `monitorListingsUsingEventEmitter` seems to ignore the `client` parameter.

Comment: yes i know that i just made  it empty  for now
i will use it later

Comment: added `pipline` as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer.
I just checked https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/.

Actully i have use

```
const changeStream = await members.watch(pipeline);
```

above statement should be like this.
its working now

```
const changeStream = await members.watch(pipeline, { fullDocument: "updateLookup" }
//this actual answer
```

Thanks everyone for not answering :)
finally i did

Answer (score 0):

I think is working in when you directly connect to collection, so you can access fullDocument.

Ex:

```
const db = client.db('test');
const collection = db.collection('usertest');

const pipeline = [
  { $match : {operationType: 'insert'} },
];

const changeStream = collection.watch(pipeline, { fullDocument: "updateLookup" });

changeStream.on('change' , (change) => {
  console.log('New Document Inserted : ', change.fullDocument); // Woking fine
});
```

But if you do like this,

```
try {
  const pipeline = [{ $match: { operationType: "insert" } }, { $match: { "fullDocument.student": "TEST" } }];
  const changeStream = await StudentModel.watch(pipeline, { fullDocument: "updateLookup" });
  changeStream.on("change", (data) => {
    console.log("New Document Inserted : ", data.fullDocument); // Not Working
  });
}
```